# PowerShell script using Bits-Transfer does not work as Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-task, bits

I've tried utilizing other Q/A's such as [Windows Server 2008 R2 PowerShell script runs manually, but not as a scheduled task](https://serverfault.com/q/504987/) but to no avail.

Basically I've got a PoSh script (apparently that's the hot abbreviation for it nowadays) that copies a lot of large files, *one at a time*, from one server (UNC path) to the local drive.  It does this in a loop, and it uses [BITS Transfer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663885.aspx).  Roughly:

1. `Start-BitsTransfer` source/destination/asynchronous/low-priority
2. `while` that Bits job's state is still "connecting" or "transferring", `Sleep` 2 seconds (i.e. wait for it to finish)
3. Once we're out of that loop, `Complete-BitsTransfer`
4. `Write-Host` a "completed file X" msg
5. get the next file, repeat... (so yes, there's an *outer loop* over the file-list obtained from `Get-ChildItem`)

The script **works** when run from PoSh ISE, and regular PoSh console.

I've tried using `Sleep`, `Start-Sleep`, and even `[Threading.Thread]::Sleep`, thinking that that was the problem.  Then I wrapped the `.ps1` in a `.bat` and, when run from CMD, that works too.  But in all cases, the Schedule Task, whether calling the `.ps1` directly or the wrapper `.bat`, fails.

It **says** it's succeeding, but what's really happening is it starts all the transfer jobs, they get into a "Suspended" state (shown by `Get-BitsTransfer` in the PoSh window), and the task thinks everything's fine and finishes, leaving these orphaned BITS jobs that I can't even `Complete-BitsTransfer` on b/c they throw an error from that too.

Other behaviors:

- The above is what happens when I run it as my domain-admin account & let it store the pwd w/ the task.
- If I change it to a service account (which is an admin on the box), it actually **never starts** the BITS jobs at all.  It also throws the error "the user must have 'log on as batch job' rights".
- If I try to let it run as a local/builtin account, it also fails to start the BITS jobs.

Tearing my hair out here... help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MS the scheduled task has to be run under an interactive logon.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663885(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That was it! My coworker also pointed it out to me (he's more the sysadmin type; I'm just the DBA trying to automate some backup shuffling). It _sort of_ makes sense since BITS is a desktop-oriented component rather than a *server* component, but still frustrating.  Had to resort to `robocopy /J` and that's OK for now...